# Integration Of exponential Function

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I have tried almost everything, but can't solve this integral.

$$\int e^{-1/x^2} \, dx $$

Comment: thats not possible. why do you want to solve it?

Comment: @supinf why not possible

Comment: i don't know exactly why that is impossible, but somebody told me that there is no way to express the solution as a combination of elementary functions.

Comment: @supinf so you wanna tell that no curve has slope of $e { ^(-1/x^2)}$

Comment: This anti-derivative cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. Why are you trying to solve this?

Comment: I'm trying to solve this, because A friend challenged me

Answer (score 2):

To some extent, you have in fact given the answer yourself, if you have (literally) tried everything then you have proven it is impossible to integrate in terms of elementary functions. This is indeed the case.

This statement is similar to the impossibility of solving a polynomial of degree $\geq$ 5 in terms of radicals; also the impossibility of "squaring the circle", namely constructing (in a finite number of steps) a square with straight edge and compass which has the same area of a given circle; also the impossibility of trisecting a given angle with just a straight edge and compass. The proofs of these statements can be learned through the topic of Galois theory.

Comment: No, he has not proven anything by "trying everything". Just saying.

Comment: @HasanSaad why not? if it would be possible, then you would succeed if you tried the right thing.

Comment: I don't think they would have even bothered to use Galois theory if things were that easy. There is no such thing as trying everything, that is first. Second, trying something doesn't imply the ability to continue from it to reach the result. Just my 2 cents.